# Unrecognised Option/s- in Eclipse IDE with Apache Tomcat 8.0.3

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay

I am going through [Liferay In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/liferay-in-action).

The author's goes on to explain the Server Runtime with Liferay POrtal in Eclipse IDE-

Server Configuration screenshot from the Appendix A of the same book-

[image]

He suggests to change these confs.-

On the right side of the screen, open the section labeled *Publishing and select Never
Publish Automatically*. Open the section labeled *Timeouts and change both the start and stop
timeouts to 300 seconds*.
Finally, on the left side, select *Open Launch Configuration*. Select the Arguments tab and
add the following arguments to the end of the list:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m - Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties
```

Click Apply and then OK. Close and save the configuration window by clicking on the X
icon in the tab.

When I append the following arguments to the already existing list of arguments and then start the Server, it results in-

> Unrecognised Option/s-

If I Remove these, then the server starts fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the minus in `external-properties` or is ther a CRLF or blank  between - and D (- Dexternal-properties)?

Comment: @Jens- What must be it then?

Comment: @Jens- Great man. Didn't noticed that. You might want to suggest it as an answer and I will accept it. ::)))

Comment: I mean this worked for me `-Dexternal.properties=portal-developer.properties` See the dot also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you have a problem with the minus in `external-properties`. Please rename it by replacing the minus sign with a dot.